# Comparing an Operator and its Square Root

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Given a Hilbert Space $H$ and a self-adjoint, positive operator $A$ on $H$.

Is it true that $\|A^{1/2}x\| \le \|Ax\|$ for all $x \in D(A)$?

If yes, how would the proof go?

Comment: For a positive number $a$ the inequality $a^{1/2}\le a$ holds iff $a\ge 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Consider the operator $\frac{1}{4} \cdot {1}_{H}$ (i.e. one fourth times the identity on $H$). It is clearly positive definite and the inequality is not true for any nonzero $x \in H$.